# Determine whether $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k+2}{\sqrt{k^5+4}}$ converges or diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

### Question

> Determine if
>
> $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k+2}{\sqrt{k^5+4}}$$
>
> converges or diverges.

I'm looking for a proof that this sum converges in a simpler way than I've shown.

### My (ugly) work

I have the following chain of implications for $k\ge 1$:

- $k^3(3k^2 - 4k -4) \ge -16 \Longrightarrow$
- $3k^5 + 16 \ge  4k^4 + 4k^3 \Longrightarrow$
- $4k^5 + 16 \ge k^5 + 4k^4 + 4k^3 \Longrightarrow$
- $2(k^5+4)^{1/2} \ge k^{5/2} + 2k^{3/2} \Longrightarrow$
- $2k(k^5+4)^{1/2} \ge (k+2)k^{5/2} \Longrightarrow$
- $\frac{2k}{k^{5/2}} \ge \frac{k+2}{\sqrt{k^5+4}}\Longrightarrow$
- $2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^{-3/2} \ge \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k+2}{\sqrt{k^5+4}}$.

Since the sum on the left-hand side converges, the given sum also converges.

**Gross!**

Comment: This is not ugly. As long as it gives a correct demonstration, it's fine.

Comment: I'll probably just do $\frac{k+2}{\sqrt{k^5+4}} \le \frac{3k}{\sqrt{k^5}} = \frac{3}{k^{3/2}}$. It is not as strong as what you get but it is easier to discover.

Comment: limit-comparison with $\sum k^{-3/2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k+2}{\sqrt{k^5+4}} \le \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k+2}{\sqrt{k^5}} \le 3+\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{2k}{k^{2.5}}=3+2\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac1{k^{1.5}}$$

Hence it converges.